# Write hex bytes to file using fwrite (little endian issue)

Tags: c

I am trying to write hex bytes to file using fwrite but it's in wrong order due to little endian. Does anyone know an easy way to fix the problem without writing another function to swap the bytes? Thanks.

My code is actually to convert every 8 bytes binary sequence to 2 bytes hexdecimal value and write to the file. For example, 00000000 -> 00 , 00010010 -> 12, ..., and write each 2 byte result to the file.

What I used to write to the file is:

```
unsigned char hex;
char two_bytes[8]="";   // 8 bytes binary sequence

hex = strtol(two_bytes, NULL, 2);
fwrite(&hex, sizeof(hex), 1, fd);  //but write in the wrong order
```

Comment: It's unclear what representations exactly you are reading/writing...

Comment: Do you mean an 8 *bit* binary sequence? And how can it be an endian issue if you're only writing a single byte??? And your string should presumably have room for 9 chars to have room for a terminating null character. And if `two_bytes` holds 8 `0` and `1` chars, then it's really only one byte so the name is strange.

Comment: @ooga Bit order is _sometimes_ an issue in serial transmission.  But most likely OP has a byte endian concern.

Comment: No. I am not write a single byte. For example, 00000000 -> 00  00010010 -> 12, ..., and write each 2 byte result to the file.

Comment: A hex value of `12` is only a single byte.

Comment: What is it about a separate function that you're against, out of curiosity?  If it's the hassle of writing it yourself, or maybe an issue of performance, then check out byteswap.h.  There are byteswap macro functions in there.  They're about as good as it gets for this

Comment: If you want to write hex bytes to a file, use `fprintf(fd,"%02x",hex);`. Endianness is not an issue here because you're only writing one byte at a time.

Comment: I guess fprintf will just write ASCII values to the file, not hexdecimal bytes.

Comment: @user1726119, you guess wrong, the `%02x` format specifier will print the value as two hexadecimal digits.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert from whatever your host endianness is to "network endian" (big endian) with [`htonl`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/htonl).

```
hex = htonl(strtol(two_bytes, NULL, 2));
```

... if you don't mind pulling in some fancy headers.

Comment: It does not work. I mean I have to write hex values directly to file, not ASCII.

Comment: Ok, that was not clear from your question, which made it sound like the *order* of the bytes was the only issue.